# PHP email form not working- unable to submit the form

Tags: php

I downloaded a template from http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/.  I'm unable to get the email form to send.  I'm unfamiliar with php,so maybe I forgot to change something?

Here is the HTML Form info:

```
        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="method="post">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="mailto:myemail@hotmail.com">Send Your Email</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
/*
* Contact Form Class
*/


header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'myemail@hotmail.com'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}


private function validateEmail(){
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($this->email == '') { 
        return false;
    } else {
        $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
}


private function validateFields(){
    // Check name
    if(!$this->name)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check email
    if(!$this->email)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check valid email
    if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check message length
    if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }
}


private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
         "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
    }
}


function sendRequest(){
    $this->validateFields();
    if($this->response_status)
    {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
    $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

also have this in main js file:

```
BRUSHED.contactForm = function(){
$("#contact-submit").on('click',function() {
    $contact_form = $('#contact-form');

    var fields = $contact_form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_include/php/contact.php",
        data: fields,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            if(response.status){
                $('#contact-form input').val('');
                $('#contact-form textarea').val('');
            }

            $('#response').empty().html(response.html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You've got missing `"` in action attribute.

Change

```
    <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="method="post">
```

to

```
    <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="" method="post">
```

and it should work properly

Answer (score 0):

there's something wrong there or i'm simply tired?

you passed the string "method=" as action of the form and post is "assumed" like an attribute of form tag

maybe you want wrote

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="" method="post">
```